# Excel Count Unique Values From SUMPRODUCT

Tags: excel

I have a sheet that is supposed to count the number of unique reservations an agent has done. It currently counts duplicates though and I need to only count unique ones.

Here is the formula being used in the sheet:

`=SUMPRODUCT((Table_Query_from_db[client_code]=$B7)*(Table_Query_from_db[created_date_time]>=D$1)*(Table_Query_from_db[created_date_time]<D$1+1))`

This counts the number of lines/records that show up for a specific person (`$B7`) for a specific date (`D$1`).

Here is the sample of the sheet:

[image]

As you can see `B7` contains the agents number and `D1` contains the date.

Here is the dataset for that specific agent on that specific date:

[image]

There is indeed 5 reservations - but only 3 unique ones.

How do I go about getting `D7` in the first picture to come out as 3 instead of 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=SUM(IF((Table_Query_from_db[client_code]=$B7)*(Table_Query_from_db[created_date_time]>=D$1)*(Table_Query_from_db[created_date_time]<D$1+1),1/COUNTIFS(Table_Query_from_db[reservation_number],Table_Query_from_db[reservation_number],Table_Query_from_db[client_code],$B7,Table_Query_from_db[created_date_time],">=" & D$1,Table_Query_from_db[created_date_time],"<" & D$1+1)))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Comment: You've entered too many arguments for this function at `Table_Query_from_db[client_code]` in `COUNTIF`.

Comment: Works great! You're answer is missing an extra parenthesis on the very end but Excel caught and corrected that.

Comment: @WolfieeifloW that's what I get by typing it in the answer space free hand.  Fixed it.  Thanks.